# Environment variables from .bashrc not being loaded when sourced from terraform script

Tags: linux, bash, terraform

I have a script being run with terraform on an EC2 instance like so:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "bash /path/to/myscript.sh
  ]
}
```

I have some environment variables defined in the .bashrc of this instance that I would like this script to have access to. However, inside that script I put,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

as the first line, but the variables defined in .bashrc were still unset.

What do I need to do to successfully source .bashrc?

Comment: Does your `.bashrc` has something like `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return # If not running interactively, don't do anything`

Comment: Something similar to that was indeed there. Thanks! If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many times, `~/.bashrc` has a check to ensure that the settings are only applied in an interactive environment. At least this check is present by default in Ubuntu.

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Within a script, you will not have `PS1` set.

So, either remove/comment that line from your `~/.bashrc`;

or source the script like this:

```
PS1=non-empty source ~/.bashrc
```